# How Can I Find My Questions with No "Best Answer"

Tags: support, accepted-answer

What is the query string to list all of my questions with no Accepted Answer selected? I would like to bring up my ratio.

Thanks and sorry if this is a dupe.

Comment: It's not quite that simple. Wiki and closed questions don't count towards the accept rate.

Comment: @ChrisF, you mean, "it's simpler than that," right?

Comment: No - searching for `user:me hasaccepted:0` will include CW and closed questions - as well as questions with no answers. To get the number of qualifying questions you'd need to search for `user:me closed:0 wiki:0 hasanswers:1` except that `hasanswers:1` doesn't exist. Then do the same with `hasaccepted:1` to get your accept ratio.

Comment: @ChrisF if you put in an answer, then I could accept it. Which is the right thing to do. Although I do now carry a 100% accept rate, it's true that I went mad and accepted an answer for every CW too :)

Comment: I was wrong about `hasanswers` not existing, it's `answers:<n>` to return questions that have at least `<n>` answers, so you'd just need `answers:1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all your qualifying questions you'll need this search:

> user:me closed:0 wiki:0 answers:1

Then you can find all the questions that you've accepted answers for by adding `hasaccepted:1`:

> user:me closed:0 wiki:0 answers:1 hasaccepted:1

Using these searches on meta I get 14 for the first search and 12 for the second which match the statistics given when hovering over my accept rate.

So of course, to find the questions which you haven't accepted an answer for run this search:

> user:me closed:0 wiki:0 answers:1 hasaccepted:0

Which here on meta gives me 2.

See the [search page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) for a full list of the search options.

Comment: Awesome, especially the search page. Teach a person to fish...

Comment: Wait there is hovertext over the acceptance rate!? Someone needs to document all these hover texts